# How can I insert a special character at the end of each sentence?

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I tend to write very long sentences. To easily detect sentences that are too long, I would like to make individual sentences stand out more clearly in my compiled latex document. I know that latex has some way of detecting the end of sentences to adjust the spacing. So is it possible to modify latex's detect-end-of-sentence function so that a highly-visible special character, say a `$\bullet$`, is inserted at the end of each sentence?

(Any other ideas to highlight sentences are very welcome.)

Answer (score 4):

To add bullets, you can make the period an active character and define a macro that adds the bullets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup       % EDIT
\let\origdot=.
\catcode`.=\active
\def.{\origdot\ensuremath{\bullet}}
Hello.  I am a sentence.  Mr.\@ Black knows too little.
\endgroup         % EDIT
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: screenshot of results]

Note that the period after `Mr` also got a bullet.  I do not know off-hand how to change that.  (Someone who does, please feel free to edit!)

An easier way may be just to add lots of space after each sentence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nonfrenchspacing    % <-- 
\xspaceskip1cm       % <-- (or whatever amount of space you prefer)
Hello.  I am a sentence.  Mr.\@ Black knows too little.
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: second screenshot]

See [this forum thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1451#p5481) for explanation.  This fixes the problem after `Mr.` (thanks to @ Gustavo Mezzetti).

Comment: What do you mean by "make the period and active character"?

Comment: This is a very short answer and just refers to a another forum, in my point of view. It does not show how to make `.` active!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer edited :)

Comment: I think you mean `Mr.~Black`, not `Mr\@. Black`.  Or `Mr.\@ Black`, if you want to allow a line break after “Mr.”, while suppressing the longer space.

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately the active character approach does not work for me. I have a few lines like `\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{fig}`. The dot inside the square bracket gets replaced as well, which leads to a compile error.

Comment: Added `\begingroup`/`endgroup`, which you can use to localize changes to areas of text.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks for the bugfix - edited!

Comment: Well, I wanted to show you the correct position of the`\@`, but `Mr.\ Black` is what I would actually use in order to permit a line break.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of the other answer is certainly better, but heres what I came up with: You want to replace periods, so do just that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\section{original tex} %one paragraph from lipsum package
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, %cut that here

\section{with replacement}

\StrSubstitute{Lorem ipsum dolor s... }{.}{.\par~\par\noindent}

\end{document}
```

of course this has the same problem that not every period is the end of a sentence and more (foremost: this only works on plain text)

[image: example]

Comment: I want to be able to quickly turn the modification on and off, because obviously in the final document I would not want any bullets between my sentences. So the only way this approach would be practical for me is to wrap the entire document body in the `StrSubstitute`. But this gives me an error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 438.` It does work when I wrap individual paragraphs, but as I said this is impractical.

Comment: which is what I anticipated. The thing is: You will always almost have to go through the text for all the non-"ending of a sentence" occurrences of a dot. The best way around from my perspective would be to change spacings, see cxw answer

Comment: I think there should be some way to tell the latex compiler: If you detect end-of-sentence, then insert a bullet and then do whatever you would normally do.

Comment: @sieste As far as I know, TeX doesn't have a "detect end-of-sentence" function similar to `\everypar`.  Instead, TeX tracks the `\spacefactor` of individual characters and adds glue between words depending on the `\spacefactor`.  See pgs. 75-76 of the TeXbook with 1996 corrections (ISBN 0-201-13448-9).

Comment: in principle you could change the \sfcode for .  (say to 17835 or something unique) but that doesnt suffice, you would then have to include a switch in the space handling of tex. no idea how that works